# How do I seal and paint over an indoor brick/cement wall?

Tags: walls, paint, brick

I am decorating a small room where a small section near the floor used to be covered by tile and just above it the paint and plaster were chipping. I removed the damaged paint and plaster as well as the tile and I am left by this exposed brick/cement area that is cold to the touch and ever so slightly moist. The brick/cement work appears to be slightly flush with the drywall around it and the previous tiles were not flush with the rest of the wall.

How do I seal this area correctly so I can paint over it?

Thanks!

[image: Indoor stone wall that gets cold]

Comment: For starters, you need to determine that moisture is not coming out of the wall. (Moisture will cause any substance to not bond to the wall.) You can easily test the wall by taping a piece of plastic over the entire exposed area. Seal the edges tight. If you use clear plastic you can check on the moisture by visually looking through the plastic instead of removing the plastic to check.

Comment: @LeeSam Yes, I'll do that. If there is no moisture coming out of the wall what do I do next?

If there is moisture what happens then?

Comment: If there is moisture, you’ll need to find the cause and stop it. (It might just be a few drops after 8-10 days.) if no moisture, I’d find a paint sealer rated for cement. Make sure both the sealer and primer and paint are rated for cement.